# Multimedia/codecs issue

Tags: 16.10, multimedia, codecs, ubuntu-restricted-extras

After upgrading my 16.04LTS to 16.10 last night, neither videos nor music is playing with standard players (rhythmbox, etc). It is definitely a codec issue b/c vlc player works fine.

I reinstalled ubuntu-restricted-extras, rebooted the machine, no progress.
How can I diagnose the problem further? Is there a way to see which codecs are "registered" in the system?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the fix is to 
(1) uninstall pulseaudio (sudo apt-get remove pulseaudio)
(2) reboot the machine.